# Where stellarium get his data on planets?

Tags: data-request, astronomy

I wonder where [stellarium](http://stellarium.org/) get his data on all the planets, like the position, rotation etc...

I've searched a little on their GitHub but I couldn't find anything.

If there's any way to get that data with an API it'll be better

Thanks for your help :-)